# Range 1004 of object _Global failed

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I have recorded a macro and if I use new data (it will always change each month) it keeps giving me the below error (with asterisks). The macro works perfectly fine with the original data I created the macro with. I have not used macros for a long time so I would appreciate a simplified description of what to do! Thanks

```
Range("AK5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Received"
Range("AL5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "No. of Students"
Range("AM5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Student Name"
Range("AN5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Student ID"
Range("AO5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Month"
Range("AP5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Department"
Range("AQ5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Type"
Range("AR5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "YoS"
**Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Received]:[YoS]]").Select**
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[YoS]]").Activate
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: You either don't have a table called Table1 on the activesheet or the table doesn't have Received or YoS as header names.

Comment: If this is happening on one worksheet, what is its (tab) name? Is the code located in the same workbook?

Comment: @Warcupine strange as I recorded the macro.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the tab name is Sheet1. I seem to have fixed it though by not trying to change the colour of those particular cells (Received:YoS). Thanks for your replies.

Comment: The macro recorder, afaik, never takes the sheet object it always defaults to the active sheet.